# java -cp . test.java Vs java test.java

Tags: java

i have one basic questions around java program execution on command prompt.

On some machines we need to specify -cp . (classpath) while executing the java program
(test is the java file name and .class file exists in the same directory)

```
java -cp . test
```

whereas some machines do not require it

```
java test
```

although both the machines have path variable defined in environment variables, have same jdk version

Comment: Check the CLASSPATH variable. I bet it's set on the machines that don't require a `-cp` (classpath) argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the code with your **classpath** then we are using the **java -cp**.
Also if you have an runnable jar and you want to run the class which is not use as runnable class  at the time of jar creation then also you use the java -cp

If you directly want to run your java file without class path and also the runnable jar as well you can directly use **java** command.

Answer (score 0):

cp command is classpath command-line .If you don’t specify classpath,the default classpath is the current directory. If you want to include the current directory in the search path, then you must include a dot (.) in the new settings.

Class path entries that are neither directories nor archives (.zip or JAR files) nor the asterisk (*) wildcard character are ignored.

For more, you can see [Setting the Class Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)